# Why is my code inserting a new line when not requested?

Tags: c, file, encryption

I am running a simple decryption function and printing the plain text onto a file. The problem is that right at the previous-to-last line, the code inserts a new line that is nonexistent in the original encrypted file.

Note this is an exercise and [it's a requirement for my task that I don't use any <s>library</s> header other than `<stdio.h>`, `<stdlib.h>`, `<stdbool.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75163897/why-is-my-code-inserting-a-new-line-when-not-requested#comment132638481_75163897).

This is the part of the code in question. I am using the for loops to wipe both arrays.

```
printf("Introdueix el nom de l'arxiu el qual vols desencriptar. Es creara l'arxiu Text_desxifrat.txt amb el contingut desencriptat\n");

scanf("%s", n_arxiu);
fit_x = fopen(n_arxiu, "r");
fit = fopen("Text_desxifrat.txt", "w");
if (fit_x == NULL) printf("Error en obrir el fitxer\n");
else{
    while (fgets(text_xifrat, MAX*2, fit_x) != NULL){
        desxifrar_frase(text_xifrat, m_clau, text);
        fprintf(fit, "%s\n", text);
        for (i = 0; (text[i] > 64 && text[i] < 91) || (text[i] == 32) || (text[i] > 48 && text[i] < 58); i++) text[i] = '\0';
        for (i = 0; (text_xifrat[i] > 64 && text_xifrat[i] < 91) || (text_xifrat[i] == 32) || (text_xifrat[i] > 48 && text_xifrat[i] < 58); i++) text_xifrat[i] = '\0';
    }
    fclose(fit_x);
    fclose(fit);
```

This is the void function desxifrar_frase used in the code before.

```
void desxifrar_frase(char frase[], char matriu_x[][7], char frase_desxifrada[]){
    int i = 0, comptador = 0, fila, col;

    while (frase[i+1] > 64 && frase[i+1] < 91){
        fila = trobar_element(frase[i], true, matriu_x);
        col = trobar_element(frase[i+1], false, matriu_x);
        frase_desxifrada[comptador] = matriu_x[fila][col];
        comptador++;
        i+=2;
    }
}
```

The next is the function trobar_element, that searches for the unencrypted value having its coordinates. It returns the ascii value of a capital letter.

```
int trobar_element(char element, bool fila, char matriu_x[][7]){
    bool trobat = false;
    int i = 0, valor;
    if (fila){
        while (!trobat){
            if (element == matriu_x[i][0]){
                valor = i;
                trobat = true;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    else{
        while (!trobat){
            if (element == matriu_x[0][i]){
                valor = i;
                trobat = true;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    return valor;
}
```

I have the original file with the following content:

```
Soneto a una nariz
Erase un hombre a una nariz pegado
erase una nariz superlativa
erase una nariz sayon y escriba
era Ovidio Nason mas naridado
muchisima nariz tan fiera
que en la cara de Anas fuera delito
Quevedo
```

And this is the content of the file when ran through the code:

```
Soneto a una nariz
Erase un hombre a una nariz pegado
erase una nariz superlativa
erase una nariz sayon y escriba
era Ovidio Nason mas naridado
muchisima nariz tan fiera
que en la cara de Anas fuera delito

Quevedo
```

I have tried removing the \n in

```
fprintf(fit, "%s\n", text);
```

but it will return every line of the original file crammed together except for the last line (Quevedo), which will be the only word in the next line.

Comment: Why on earth are you squidging this whole `for` loop — `for (i = 0; (text[i] > 64 && text[i] < 91) || (text[i] == 32) || (text[i] > 48 && text[i] < 58); i++) text[i] = '\0';` onto a single line?  Why are you squidging the longer `for` loop onto a single line on the next line?  It makes your code hard to read.  And you're seeking help, so you should aim to make your code easy to read and understand.  Writing it as you have is not idiomatic C.  There are functions `isupper()` and `isdigit()` in `<ctype.h>` that make the condition easier to write and read.

Comment: `fgets()` lets you know you got an entire line of text by _not removing_ the newline from the input string. You have to do that yourself. I tend to use `strpbrk( s, "\n\r" )` to find it and set it to `'\0'`.

Comment: Why do you call ```fopen``` twice bug check its return value only once? Could the other ```FILE *``` not be NULL?

Comment: You run `fclose()` on the two file streams even if they failed — you need to ensure you don't try using the streams if either of them failed to open.

Comment: I don't check for the second file as it is a file I am creating, where the output will be printed in. Should I check even though it didn't exist before?

Comment: Yes, but how would you know if the file was created or not if you don't check for it? :)

Comment: What does the function `trobar_element()` do?  What are the two loops I've complained about supposed to do?  AFAICS, they both zap upper-case letters, digits and spaces to null bytes, leaving anything else (such as a newline) unchanged.  You don't show the definitions for the variables, so we can't compile and reproduce your code.  Please create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)
 — the same idea by a different name).

Comment: I forgot to add to the original entry that I can't use <string.h>, that's why I'm using the odd for loops.

Comment: Always check the result of every file open operation.  There can be many reasons why it will fail — and the results of ignoring the possibility are never beneficial.  Usually, your program will crash.

Comment: What about `<ctype.h>`?  What about `<stdlib.h>`?  Petty restrictions like that are put in place to encourage you to learn the fundamentals of what's in the library and how such functions might be written.  We see such limitations frequently — but it is important to identify them when asking the question.  I think that `text[0] = '\0';` should be sufficient as a replacement for the first `for` loop and `text_xifrat[0] = '\0';` for the second.  If you need to set all bytes to null, use the equivalent of `memset()`; you'll write your own since the official version is declared in `<string.h>`.

Comment: It's a requirement for my task that I don't use any library other than <stdio.h>, <stdlib.h>,<stdbool.h>

Comment: I need the arrays to be completely wiped clean, just so when I overwrite them, the previous input won't be visible (in the case the previous input had more characters than the current one).

Comment: Write a function such as `static inline bool is_upper_digit_space(char c) { return (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c == ' ') || (c >= '0' && c <= '9'); }` and call it to test the condition in your loops, if you really need to leave punctuation, lower-case letters and control characters alone.  Note the use of character constants to identify the ranges more sanely (and the change from `<` to `<=` and from `>` to `>=`).  Using a function ensures that the condition is the same in both loops.

Comment: Then you need a `memset()` workalike that zeroes all the bytes — though if you are working with null-terminated strings and don't read beyond the null-terminator, the simple assignments are perfectly adequate.  There is a small risk that information could leak, so zeroing the entire string is a good idea in secure applications, but it slows the code down.  Optimizers also try to eliminate such code.  However, those are (probably) details beyond what you need to worry about now.

Comment: Fixed it using a `memset()` workalike. I ended up replacing the whole array with the null-terminator, instead of just the parts with capital letters, as you recommended in the beginning. Thanks to everyone for your help.